# How to set a timeout for gurobi using python

Tags: python, timeout, gurobi

I want to solve ILPs using the python interface to gurobi. I also want to set a timeout of 5 minutes. I tried

```
e = gurobipy.Env()
e.setParam('TimeLimit', 5*60)
m = gurobipy.Model(env=e)
```

but i get the error

> File "env.pxi", line 18, in gurobipy.Env.**init**
>   (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:2821) TypeError: **init**() takes exactly
>   2 positional arguments (1 given)

although according to the documentation `gurobipy.Env()` doesn't have parameters without default values. Also, in the documentation it says

> Env() creates a client environment on a compute server.

so I am wondering if this is even the most efficient way to set a simple time limit for gurobi. What's a good way to timelimit gurobipy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simply set the time limit on the model itself:

```
m = gurobipy.model()
m.setParam('TimeLimit', 5*60)
```

Comment: or the way I prefer:
`m.Params.TimeLimit = 5*60`